# Which one is faster and preferable when doing aggregate function to the data in sql? CASE WHEN or WHERE?

Tags: sql

I have following simple sql code to select the number of rows that meet a specific criteria:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN /*condition*/ THEN 1 END) FROM table_name;
```

Verus

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE /*condition*/;
```

Both of them seems to work the same when I only want to do some aggregate function to the data.

I have two questions:

1. Which one has faster performance speed?
2. Which one is commonly preferable by developers (when doing aggregate function)?

Thanks for any responds!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question lacks any indication of what the code is intended to achieve. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the purpose of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. The title needs an [edit] to simply [state the task](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual answer to "which way is faster" usually depends on your DB.  The way to find out is to use your DB's "explain" tool to see how it's providing the answer to your query.

As to your other question, I've never see `COUNT(CASE WHEN /*condition*/ THEN 1 END)` in the 30yrs I've been working with DBs.

I had to think about it, to even be sure it'd work.  As it relies on an implicit `else null` and that the count function ignores NULL.

In your case, I'd expect them to be the same for most DB's.  However, that's only because I'd expect most DB's to rewrite the query into the same form of
`COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE /*condition*/`
This form of the query can definitely take advantages of indexes, whereas the other form might not.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Just one question, in my mind, don't the `SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN /*condition*/ THEN 1 END) FROM table_name;` a little bit faster since `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE /*condition*/;` will first loop over the whole table and filter the unneeded result and again loop over the table to count the number of them, but `SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN /*condition*/ THEN 1 END) FROM table_name;` will need 1 loop and you will get the result. Does it work like this way? I am new to SQL, please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: @James  The query engine is perfectly capable of counting while filtering; thus there wouldn't be two loops.  Thing to understand is that the query engine will try to use indexes first and foremost for the criteria in the `WHERE` clause.  It may not need to read the actual table at all.  Without a where clause, the query engine will need to read through the entire table.